# Yii separate authentication for module and app

Tags: authentication, yii, module

I have some question about yii authentication.

can yii create authentication for module and for site separated authentication. for example I have module learnings it will have it's own authentication. and also site has own authentication.

somesite/login - this will be site login

somesite/module_name/login - this will be module authentication

and then it can't access user from site login to module actions and

user from module login can't access site actions

where need authentication

Answer (score 1):

let assume Admin is your module ,

Inside your `admin/AdminModule.php` file, add the following lines to the 'init' function

```
Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
            'errorHandler' => array(
                'errorAction' => 'admin/default/error',
            ),
            'user' => array(
                'class' => 'CWebUser',
                'stateKeyPrefix' => '_admin',
                'loginUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->getId() . '/default/login'),
            ),
        ));
```

for more info  [Module based login yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/616/how-to-create-module-based-login/)

Comment: Yes this is the good way but I have some problem with it. after login on module and app. I try to logout when I logout in module application also logged out. so how to decide this issue? thank you for your answer.

Comment: if so , create your own logout action.. unset necessary sessions variable

Comment: now I have different actions logout for app and for module. but when I logout from module app also logged out.